# Which filter to use when measuring the voltage power line, common mode filter and/or differential mode filter?

Tags: adc, filter, voltage-measurement

I'm using an 78M6631 IC for three phase metering. For voltage measurement, the datasheet recommends a voltage divider. Researching through internet is recommended to include a filter, I don't get when to use common mode filter or differential (or both), because I don't know if I have to treat the measure as a differential input signal that needs common mode filtering.

Also when trying to design the filter, I realized that the common mode filter can introduce a phase shift in the input which is really undesirable. I even read that ADCs have high CMRR. Could i get away using only the differential mode filter or the common mode filter is necessary for better accuracy and precision?

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/696836/edit) the question to include the part number of the ``IC with a 24-bit ADC`` which is being used. Perhaps the manufacturer of the IC has reference design(s) for three phase metering which could be used to help select the filtering.

Comment: Done, i specified the IC. Other approach i was thinking about is employing the differential mode filter with an inductor (RLC) so the inductor could filter high frequency noise, and may be adding to the inductor at neutral for the same purpose.

Comment: _Figure 5: 78M6631 Evaluation Board Electrical Schematic (1 of 3)_ in the [UG-5263: 78M6631 Evaluation Board User Manual](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/78m6631-evaluation-board-user-manual.pdf) appears to show a _Differential mode filter_ in use. In that manual can't seem to find a description of _why_ the particular filter was selected for the evaluation board. I don't have sufficient knowledge to provide a specific recommendation for how to select a filter.

Comment: In what way is the circuit shown, a common-mode filter? The terminology is not clear to me. Perhaps it would be more apparent in a wider section of the circuit?